# Angular2 RC5 | Router: Cannot match any routes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, module, router

I am currently using Angular 2 - RC5 with the router 3.0.0 RC1. This seems to be a pretty common error, but I can't find any solution that works. My component structure includes a "BasicContentComponent" which includes the main menu and the header and an aux outlet for the content of the child route. The "BasicContentComponent" comes from a shared module and the child routes component from specific module of that child route.

My route configuration looks like this

```
export const routeConfig = [
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: BasicContentComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: HomeContainer,
                //canActivate: [IsAuthenticatedGuard],
                outlet: 'content', // REMOVE THIS LINE
                //resolve: {
                //    homeState: HomeResolver
                //}
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

If I remove the "children" definition I am able to load "/home" but with this configuration I get the error.

Following are the module configurations, since the problem may also lie there.

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,

    RouterModule.forRoot(routeConfig), //see above
    SharedModule.forRoot(),
    HomeModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**shared.module.ts**

```
import { Store, StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule,
        CommonModule,
        ...

        StoreModule.provideStore(reducers),
    ],
    declarations: [
        BasicContentComponent,
        ...
    ],
    exports: [BasicContentComponent, ...],

})
export class SharedModule {

    static forRoot() : ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: SharedModule,
            providers: [
                MdIconRegistry,
                ...
                IsAuthenticatedGuard,
                ...
                HomeResolver
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**home.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, SharedModule],
    declarations: [
        HomeContainer,
        HomeComponent
    ],
    exports: [HomeContainer]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

I get the following error

> browser_adapter.js:84 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error:
>   Cannot match any routes: 'home'

Any idea what the problem could be? Is it a route config or a modules issue? thanks

**Edit**
I forgot the templates:

**app.component.html**

```
<div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**basic-content.component.html**

```
<md-sidenav-layout fullscreen>
  <md-sidenav mode="side" align="start" [opened]="isOpened$ | async" color="warn">
    <mainnav-container></mainnav-container>
  </md-sidenav>

  <page-header-container></page-header-container>

  <div class="app-content">
    <router-outlet name="content"></router-outlet> // REMOVE NAME
  </div>

</md-sidenav-layout>
```

Comment: The HomeContainer. The hierarchy looks like AppComponent -> BasicContentComponent (loaded in default <router-outlet> of the AppComponent) -> HomeContainer (loaded in <router-outlet name='content'> of the BasicContentComponent) - **This was an answer to a deleted comment**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got help on Gitter. If I remove the "name" attribute of the router-outlet and also remove it from the routerConfig everything works as intended. I don't fully understand why I have to remove it and how exactly the router finds the correct outlet - it makes kinda sense since the outlets are nested - but I will udpate my answer at a later point when the documentation for named outlets is more complete.

Thanks to @DzmitryShylovich on Gitter.

Comment: I'm having this issue on angular 2.0.0 router v3.  I get this error wether I use the outlet parameter or not, and wether I name my router-outlet or not.  Everything breaks as soon as I add `children:`

Comment: I found out what my issue is/was.  If you use webpack to lazy load, you have to create another `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`, not for the component you are loading that is part of the ngModule you are lazy loading, but for any other components that lazy loaded ngModule loads (I hope that makes sense).  So If I try and use `children:` in my lazy loaded routes, i would then need to create a 3rd `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`.  Point is, there's no reason to use `children:` in my lazy loaded ngModule routes config because all of the routes are acting as child routes already.